# Scroll bar is seen only when there is overflow

Tags: css, html, overflow

Scroll bar should be seen only when there is overflow else it should be hidden.But by default it is displaying scrollbar although div has appropriate non overflow content.
How we can stop that?

```
<body>
  <p>The overflow property specifies what to do if the content of an element exceeds the              size of the element's box.</p>

  <p>overflow:scroll</p>
  <div class="scroll">You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.</div>


 </body>
```

CSS:

```
div.scroll
{
  background-color:#00FFFF;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Comment: `overflow:auto;` will do this. It's set by default.

Comment: @Sync Circles: Please add that as answer. Or should I delete this stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`overflow:auto;` will do this.

```
div.scroll
{
  background-color:#00FFFF;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```